# Firebase cloud function onUpdate child of list (NodeJs)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

How to trigger the firebase cloud function onUpdate

each time any of the child
"order_status" is **== "accepted"**

(included the old Childs on trigger)

my code won't work

Have a look please :

[image]
**Code:**

```
  exports.checkOrderStatus = functions.database.ref("/RestaurantOrders").onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
        
            var orderStatus = change.after.val().order_status;
        
            if (orderStatus == "accepted") {
         code...
        
        } else {

        return 
    
    }

    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe exactly what you're doing that should trigger the function.  If there are specific cases where it does or does not work the way you expect, make that clear in your examples.  There should be enough information in the question so that anyone can reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Ok , i edited the question. @DougStevenson

Comment: I'm still not at all clear.  You should know that your code will only trigger when a new child is added, it will receive only the data from that child, and it will not know anything about any other children previously added.

Comment: Yes! you got me, how can I loop over all the child to check each one if the order_status has "accepted" value, if you can help me to edit my question, sorry my English is bad..

Comment: You will have to writ code to query for the children that you want.  It won't come in the snapshot of the trigger.

Comment: Oh okay I thought I can use the reference From the listener , so I loop with the same reference path  and then in foreach I retrieve the value?

Comment: I Updated again the Question

Answer (score 0):

```
  exports.checkOrderStatus = functions.database.ref("/RestaurantOrders/{pushId}").onUpdate((change, context) => {
        
            var orderStatus = change.after.val().order_status;
        
            if (orderStatus == "accepted") {
         code...
        
        } else {

        return 
    
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm using realTime database, still doesn't work. each child of this list has a child named orderStatus and I want to check his value, I think I need to loop right ?

Comment: I have edited my answer with `onWrite()` try it and also remove `asyn`

Comment: onWrite() trigger when child is created , I want to trigger the function only when the existing orders updates to "accepted"

Comment: Read it https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#function_triggers